# To call two different variables in mat-cell(td) in the table component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using a basic `table` component. Here in the **2nd column** (i,e **Booking**),I want to display 2 variables in the same column, one is of type `number(ex 21)` and another is of `string(ex participants)`.
Something like this:

[image]

Because the 2nd variable `(i,e participants)` i am using it as `hyperlink`.

I tried but ended up like this:

[image]

Means i am displaying variable `(i, pariticipents)` in the 3rd column also, But **I want to display  variable (i, pariticipents) in in 2n column only** and some other data in 3rd column(i,e Staff) like in the `1st image`.

Comment: Not able to understand your question. Add problem statement separately with expected behavior

Comment: okay i will update the question.

Comment: Please see the updated question @ShabbirDhangot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your display column list. You can remove extra column that you want to concatenate with other.

I have updated stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g23zsu

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'symbol'];
```

Comment out extra column code and append to any column

```
<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} -- {{element.weight}}</td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Weight Column -->
<!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  </td>
</ng-container> -->
```